# 3D-CRT vs. IMRT in Radiotherapy

Tags: medical-physics

I'm having some trouble truly understanding the difference between these two.

As far as I know, the 3D-CRT is just beams from different angles, where you can modulate the beam intensity by lead blocks custom made for each patient, cut out to fit the outline of a tumour.

IMRT is when the Multileaf Collimator (MLC) is introduced. So you have a step-and-shoot option, where the MLC is static during treatment, and then the sliding window technique where you can move the collimators real time during treatment.

Is this correctly understood ?

I think my main concern is, that I maybe thought/think that MLCs are also used in 3D-CRT. But maybe it turns into IMRT when MLCs are used, or...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know that we have any active radiation-health-physicists (is anyone even certain where the hyphens are supposed to go?) on the site, which is a shame because it is a emerging field.

Comment: I think this is more of an engineering than a physics question. We can talk about penetration depth of different types of radiation, interaction with matter etc.. but the implementation/classification of radiotherapy devices would be clearly outside of the responsibility of physics proper.

Comment: @CuriousOne As a matter of practice hospitals that do this kind of thing employ physicists (at least in the US). The title is usually "radiation physicist" or something similar. The pay is pretty good, the work is reported to be challenging enough to be interesting, and I'm told that the MD's actually respect the physics guys. That said, it is rather an application field rather than a science field.

Comment: The line between applied physics and engineering is blurry but this doesn't cross it IMO.

Comment: @dmckee: Oh, I am fully aware of the role of physicists in radiation therapy, I just don't subscribe to the definition "physics is what physicists do". If that's what physics is then financial spreadsheets would be physics, too. I know more than one quant who has gotten his PhD in quantum field theory... having said that, I didn't vote to close and I won't. It's grey enough for me to let someone take it and use it to give an interesting answer.

Comment: Ah ... I see it as equivalent to asking about the nomenclature and operation of experimental equipment because these are the tools that a radiation physicist uses to design and control a localized dosing program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a medical physicist working in a Radiation Oncology department.

MLCs are used for both 3D and IMRT plans. In fact, very few hospitals have the ability to make/use the lead blocks anymore. The MLCs define the shape of the radiation field.

3D treatment plans are generated with the user (often the MD) defining the MLC shapes for each gantry angle, and then a dosimetrist or physicist will determine the appropriate energy and "weighting" of each beam to achieve a desired dose distribution that will accomplish the clinical objective. Typically, 3D plans have a single shape per gantry angle, but this is not necessarily the case.

IMRT is also sometimes referred to as "inverse planning" because the clinical objectives are put into the Treatment Planning System, which will then determine the optimal MLC shapes to accomplish the goals. IMRT plans have multiple MLC shapes per gantry angle.

I hope this answers your question. I am happy to go into more detail.